# Two servers with identical config - ldap_bind works on one, fails on the other

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, ldap

I just rolled out a development server with identical config as production (CentOS 6.5, same AMP stack).  In the past, I had to run the development instance on the same machine (under a different IP-based virtualhost).  ldap_bind worked perfectly in the old monobox setup.

I have separate ssl crt files for production and development (`prod` & `dev`).  After setting up the new machine (using puppet - same config as production), I copied over the development crt files and ensured the apache config loaded OK. Same IP address is used for development as before.

When I try to authenticate against ldap on the development system, I'm getting the following error:

> PHP Warning:  ldap_bind() [function.ldap-bind]: Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /some/path/function/functions_security.php on line 1234, referer: http://my.application.com/somescript.php

Line 1234 of somescript.php is

> $r = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $srvc_dn, $srvc_pass);

No need in posting the parameters because they are **identical** between production and development systems.  Production works flawlessly.

I've confirmed that there are no firewall or network issues on the development machine  telnetting to the ldap server under the supplied port.  I'm able to connect just fine.

The network ops guy said the reason the requests are failing is because I haven't "imported the certificates to the store" on the development system.  I've googled a bit, but maybe I'm not using the right keywords - I'm not finding how to check what certificates are in my development "key store".

I saw some documentation for `keytool`, where it can list certificates in a .jks file - but I cannot find a .jks file on either production or development systems.

Some leads/search keywords/suggestions would be very helpful, as I am currently stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do two things to get this working.

1) Copied my server certs to the `TLS_CACERTDIR` in `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`.

2) Ran `/usr/sbin/cacertdir_rehash` on `TLS_CACERTDIR`.  This step is apparently important since I'm using CentOS 6.

After this, LDAP worked with `ldapsearch` and with PHP's `ldap_bind`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe certificates are stored at `/etc/pki/tls/certs/` on CentOS. You can compare what's there on your development machine to what's there on your production machine

Comment: On both machines the crt files are stored under `/usr/local/ssl/crt`.  Both systems use the same OS (and software config via puppet).  These are two new systems, and for the production machine I just copied the crt files (after creating the directory structure above), ensured apache ssl.conf pointed to them, and ldap_bind just worked.

Answer (score 0):

From any machine that has openssl installed (i guess both of your centos machines do), try `openssl s_client -connect myserver:ldaps`. Substitue myserver with your server name and ldaps with the port if it's not the standard (636). Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and scroll back to after the command. You should see something like

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 /C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
verify return:1
depth=1 /C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
verify return:1
depth=0 /description=zACEv54DP1HaZ8cR/C=DE/CN=XXXX.xxxx.xxxx.com/emailAddress=webmaster@xxxxxxx.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/description=zACEv54DP1HaZ8cR/C=DE/CN=xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.com/emailAddress=webmaster@xxxxxxx.com
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
 1 s:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Class 1 Primary Intermediate Server CA
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
 2 s:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
   i:/C=IL/O=StartCom Ltd./OU=Secure Digital Certificate Signing/CN=StartCom Certification Authority
---
```

Your CA will be different, but this example shows the certificates including CA certificates that are installed on the server. Check if there's a difference between prod and dev that can't be explained by the prod/dev crt file, or if there isn't a difference where there should be (the CN=xxxx.xxx part). This might help you find out what's wrong with the certificates. Or, if you do not get `CONNECTED(00000003)` on one of the servers, then ldap isn't running there.

Another thing: you say `I copied over the development crt files`. Did you copy the key as well? Did you restart the ldap server after copying the files?

Comment: I used s_client earlier, but only saw the certificate of the remote LDAP server I'm attempting to authenticate against.  Should I see my local certificates in the chain as well?  Keys and certificates were copied and are properly referenced in my Apache ssl.conf file.

Comment: fwiw I'm getting identical server chains on both systems using `openssl s_client -connect ldap.service.company.com`

Comment: Sorry, seems i misunderstood. I got the impression you were running an LDAP server on each of your machines locally, with one of them using the dev certs, the other using the prod certs. If both machines use the certs for the web server only, and both connect to the same LDAP server (that is not running on one of your machines), you should see the same chain of course. Maybe the certificates of the prod apache server and the ldap server use the same CA, but the dev uses a different one? Try `ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);` before the connect, maybe you get something useful.

Comment: Still nothing new in setting debug to 7.  Same error as before: `Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server`

Comment: Any debug messages? Did you check /var/log/httpd/error_log? The next thing i'd do if i were in your situation would be taking a tcpdump of both machines when they run the ldap script and compare these dumps using wireshark. Don't know how proficient you are with network dumps though.

Comment: That's where I'm getting the error message (error_log).  The error log is the same before and after setting debug per your post "6 hours ago" - wish there was a full timestamp.   I'm not proficient with TCP dumps.  Hopefully this is something easy to pick up on.

Comment: I think this is what I want to capture traffic:  `tcpdump -s 1514 port 636 -w capture_file` (?)

Comment: Got wireshark installed.  production looks clean.  development tcpdump reports "Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unknown CA)".

Comment: The "Description: Unknown CA" hints to me that you use one (self-made?) CA for the prod certificate and the ldap server, and a different one for the dev machine, so the dev machine doesn't have the root certificate of your LDAP CA.

Comment: No self-made certs in play here.   I had to do two things to get this working.  1) copied my server certs to the `TLS_CACERTDIR` in `/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`.  2) ran `/usr/sbin/cacertdir_rehash` on `TLS_CACERTDIR`.  Then LDAP worked with `ldapsearch` and with PHP's `ldap_bind`.